# R - Vectorized implementation of ternary operator?

Tags: r, vectorization

The title says it about as well as I can. What I have:

```
A     B
TRUE  FALSE
FALSE TRUE
TRUE  TRUE
```

what I want:

```
C
if(A[1]&&B[1]){some.value.here}else if(A[1]){other.value}else{another.value}
if(A[2]&&B[2]){some.value.here}else if(A[2]){other.value}else{another.value}
if(A[3]&&B[3]){some.value.here}else if(A[3]){other.value}else{another.value}
```

I've tried `ifelse` but only got atomic results not vectors.

Comment: Is that a data frame that A and B are a part of?

Comment: No, A and B are just vectors on their own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ifelse` works fine if with a little nesting. (It would have been nice to see your attempt to figure out where you went wrong.)

```
A = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
B = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
C = ifelse(A & B, "both", ifelse(A, "A only", "not A"))
cbind(A, B, C)

#      A       B       C        
# [1,] "TRUE"  "FALSE" "A only" 
# [2,] "FALSE" "TRUE"  "not A"
# [3,] "TRUE"  "TRUE"  "both"
```

Comment: I used `ifelse(A && B, "Both" , ifelse(A, "Just A" , "Not A"))` which I now realize is wrong b/c of using `&&` instead of `&`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a data frame with two columns, try using conditionals.

As a placeholder for your real replacement values, I chose `"justA"`, `"justB"`, and `"both"`.

```
df$result[df$A & df$B] <- "both"
df$result[df$A & !df$B] <- "justA"
df$result[df$B & !df$A] <- "justB"

df
      A     B result
1  TRUE FALSE  justA
2 FALSE  TRUE  justB
3  TRUE  TRUE   both
4 FALSE  TRUE  justB
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(A=sample(c(T,F), 4, T), B=sample(c(T,F), 4, T))
df$result <- NA
```

Answer (score 0):

If A and B are vectors:

```
> A = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
> B = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
```

You can use mapply():

```
> mapply(function (x, y) ifelse(x && y, 1, 2), A, B)
[1] 2 2 1
```

Comment: Sorry, just noticed the nature of your logic. You would need to use a nested `ifelse`, e.g. `mapply(function (x, y) ifelse(x, ifelse(y, 1, 3), 2), A, B)`